# Visual Studio - CMake - Mingw64 Configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, cmake, msys2

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to create a cross-platform C++ CMake HelloWorld project.

I've created the project using the Visual Studio 2019 **Linux development with C++ toolset** and created a new
[CMake Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuens.png).

The project compiles and runs fine in Linux-GCC-Debug but I'm having issues when creating a Minigw64 configuration.

I've installed MSYS2 following the instructions here: https://www.msys2.org/

I've setup the MinGW environment by installing the devel packages.

```
pacman -S make gettext base-devel
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ninja 
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
```

When I attempt to generate the CMake cache I get the following error:

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/lawsm/source/repos/HelloCmake/out/build/Mingw64-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_4b37c && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4b37c.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_4b37c.exe

FAILED: cmTC_4b37c.exe 

cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe    CMakeFiles/cmTC_4b37c.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj  -o cmTC_4b37c.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_4b37c.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

My CMakeSettings.json is this:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mingw64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "mingw_64" ],
      "environments": [
        {
          "MINGW64_ROOT": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64",
          "BIN_ROOT": "${env.MINGW64_ROOT}\\bin",
          "FLAVOR": "x86_64-w64-mingw32",
          "TOOLSET_VERSION": "7.3.0",
          "PATH": "${env.MINGW64_ROOT}\\bin;${env.MINGW64_ROOT}\\..\\usr\\local\\bin;${env.MINGW64_ROOT}\\..\\usr\\bin;${env.MINGW64_ROOT}\\..\\bin;${env.PATH}",
          "INCLUDE": "${env.INCLUDE};${env.MINGW64_ROOT}\\include\\c++\\${env.TOOLSET_VERSION};${env.MINGW64_ROOT}\\include\\c++\\${env.TOOLSET_VERSION}\\tr1;${env.MINGW64_ROOT}\\include\\c++\\${env.TOOLSET_VERSION}\\${env.FLAVOR}",
          "environment": "mingw_64"
        }
      ],
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_C_COMPILER",
          "value": "${env.BIN_ROOT}\\gcc.exe",
          "type": "STRING"
        },
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER",
          "value": "${env.BIN_ROOT}\\g++.exe",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ],
      "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
      "cmakeToolchain": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

---